# Press tabbar and call Scroll to top within prefersLargeTitles = true iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scrolltop

Trying to detect user tapped on the tab bar item then scrollToTop for the active controller with this code

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) {
      tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)                            
    }
```

It is working properly but the problem is the controller initiated with a large navigation bar title so when the controller scroll to the first row the navigation bar title doesn't back to Large title style

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -141), animated: true)
```

Here 141 is the size of the navigation bar with large titles and the status bar (97 pts + 44 pts).

Comment: Then the didSelectRowAt will not work directly, should select the row twice !

Comment: This is weird, the didSelectRowAt() should be call when a cell is selected. Maybe you need to wait that the animation is completed if you select the row programmatically, put the call of selectRowAt() (if you use this) in a completion handler after the animation.

Comment: Nice that you fixed your problem !